# pre fill text fields (in form) based on value selected from dynamic drop down box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I will start off by saying I am new to coding so i find this very difficult, also i have asked a few questions recently, mainly because i am REALLY STUCK, so all help is really appreciated.

I have two tables. Employee (Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Address etc) and Training (Training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training_type).

For the training table, I have a form in which is meant to be filled out to assign a training type for an employee.

OK currently, the dropdown box,for employee ID, has the values of the employee ID from the employee table.

When i chose a value from the drop down box, i would like for the text fields in the form (firstname & Lastname) to update showing the names for that employee_id. I have searched online but have NO idea how to do this.

Below shows my form (php)

```
<html>
   <?php
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      if (!$con)
      {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      mysql_select_db("hrmwaitrose", $con);
   ?>
   <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
      <title>Training</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="content">  
      <h1 align="center">Add Training</h1>

      <form action="inserttraining.php" method="post">
         <div>
            <p>Training ID: <input type="text" name="Training_ID"></p>
            <p>Employee ID:<select id="Employee_ID">
            <?php
               $result = mysql_query("SELECT Employee_ID FROM Employee");
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                  echo "<option value=$row[0]>$row[0]</option>";
               }
            ?>
            </select>
            <p>First name: <input type="text" name="First_name"></p>
            <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="Last_name"></p>
            <p>
               Training required?
               <select name="Training">
                  <option value="">Select...</option>
                  <option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
                  <option value="Bailer">Bailer</option>
                  <option value="Reception">Reception</option>
                  <option value="Fish & meat counters">Fish & meat counters</option>
                  <option value="Cheese counters">Cheese counters</option>
               </select>
            </p>
            <input type="submit">
         </form>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

And here is my php code for when the submit button is pressed.

```
<?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   if (!$con)
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db("hrmwaitrose", $con);

   $sql="INSERT INTO training (Training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training)
         VALUES
         ('$_POST[Training_ID]','$_POST[Employee_ID]','$_POST[First_name]','$_POST[Last_name]','$_POST[Training]')";


   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo "1 record added";

   mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I think its done by java? not too sure.

Comment: if you want to do it nice and dynamic you will need to look at AJAX

Comment: any chance you can give me some assistance with AJAX? sorry, programming is not my best skill!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view file:

```
<?php
// First of all, don't make use of mysql_* functions, those are old
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hrmwaitrose;charset=utf8", "root", "");
?>
<html>
<head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- You will need jQuery (or anyother javascript framework) to accomplish your goal cause you need ajax -->
        <title>Training</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1 align="center">Add Training</h1>

            <form action="inserttraining.php" method="post">
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Training ID:
                        <input type="text" name="Training_ID">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Employee ID:
                        <select id="Employee_ID">
                            <option value="">Select one</option>
                            <?php
                            $st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Employee_ID FROM Employee");
                            $st->execute();
                            $rows = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                                ?><option value="<?php echo $row ['Employee_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row ['Employee_ID']; ?></option><?php
                            }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    <p>
                        First name:
                        <input type="text" name="First_name" id="First_name">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Last name:
                        <input type="text" name="Last_name" id="Last_name">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Training required?
                        <select name="Training">
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                            <option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
                            <option value="Bailer">Bailer</option>
                            <option value="Reception">Reception</option>
                            <option value="Fish & meat counters">Fish & meat counters</option>
                            <option value="Cheese counters">Cheese counters</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { // This code will be executed when DOM is ready
            $('#Employee_ID').change(function() { // When the value for the Employee_ID element change, this will be triggered
                var $self = $(this); // We create an jQuery object with the select inside
                $.post("getEmployeeData.php", { Employee_ID : $self.val()}, function(json) {
                    if (json && json.status) {
                        $('#First_name').val(json.name);
                        $('#Last_name').val(json.lastname);
                    }
                })
            });
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your getEmployeeData.php file:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hrmwaitrose;charset=utf8", "root", "");

header("Content-Type:application/json; Charset=utf-8");

// As you can see, here you will have where Employee_ID = :employee_id, this will be
// automatically replaced by the PDO object with the data sent in execute(array('employee_id' => $_POST['Employee_ID']))
// This is a good practice to avoid SqlInyection attacks
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM Employee WHERE Employee_ID = :employee_id");
$st->execute(array ('employee_id' => $_POST['Employee_ID']));
$data = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array ('status' => true, 'name' => $data ['First_name'], 'lastname' => $data ['Last_name']));
```

Some last suggestions: indent the code correctly. Close every html tag (`<input />` for example)

Comment: Thank you for the help, you comments help alot! although, when i use the above code, the form only shows training_ID, and Employee_ID fields, and the employee_ID drop down box now contains no values?

Comment: just realised, i need to download jquery?

Comment: Can you include your database? I've not tested the code, if you upload at least one row of your db, I can test it and see where the problem is :)

Comment: No, it is being include from google, the problem of not showing data is with the query being executed.

Comment: oh ok! how do i include my database to this?

Comment: sorry for the hassle, the code still does not work for me? when i change employee ID from the drop down, there is no change to the first name or last name field. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: so i do not need to download jquery? and it should just work?

Comment: Yes, it should work... It is working for me... Install firebug and see if there is any error on javascript or in the ajax request.

Comment: Remember getEmployeeData.php must be in the same folder as your main script. Also, if you are using linux to deploy your application remember is not the same getemployeedata.php and getEmployeeData.php

Comment: I have both the files saved as test.php(the form) and testadd.php, they are both saved in the same folder. i cant seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: and they are both saved as php files

Comment: Cheers mate, i figured out what was wrong, i was just being stupid. THANK YOU for your help so much!

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way, you hav to implement a little ajax method (with jQuery for example) who will be triggered on the onchange attribute of your dropdown list.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var choice = jQuery(this).val();
    $.ajax({
    url:'fakeurl.test.php',
    type:'POST'
    data : {'id' : choice},
    success : function(response) {
        $('input[name="First_name"]').val(response.firstname);
        $('input[name="Last_name"]').val(response.lastname);
    }
    });
});
```

And of course, in your PHP

```
$id = $_POST['id'] ;
SELECT...WHERE employee_id = $id...
[...]
return json_encode(array(
     'lastname'=>$employee_lastname,
     'firstname'=>$employee_firstname
));
```

Comment: sorry mate, I am confused on how i implement that code^^ into my code, do you mind explaining where i insert it? or adding it to my code?. Really appreciate the help.